# Mudança de um false para true com Vuex e Axios

Tags: vue.js, front-end, vue.js-2, vuex

Atualmente tenho uma estrutura com Nuxt e Vuex no projeto, á um objeto que vem diretamente de uma Api e preciso fazer ele trocar o estado de "false" para "true" caso a API retorne ele como true, assim ele irá exibir 1 campo no menu, porem no vuex ele está salvando no localstorage e não á essa troca de estado.

Codigo do vuex

```
state: {
user: {},
}
actions: {
  async betaUpdate(context, user) {        
    const usuario = (await Axios.get(`http://api-interna/me/${usuarioId}`)).data
  }
```

dentro de user eu recebo informações como 
beta: user.beta, betachart: user.betachart,

porem nessa minha API quero verificar se internamente sempre que houver uma atualização nesses dois campos e mudar o valor de false deles para true caso a API retorne true,

no VUE coloquei um mapActions, chamando a action porem não consigo(não estou sabendo) fazer a mudança caso haja um retorno TRUE da Api a cima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O fluxo correto seria sempre alterar o state a partir de uma mutation, no caso a partir do context na action tu tens acesso as mutations (através da função commit), e aí na tua mutation mudaria o estado

```
state: {
  minhavar: false
},
mutations: {
  alteraMinhaVar(state, valor) {
    state.minhavar = valor
  }
},
actions: {
  async chamaAPI (context) {
    ...request
    context.commit('alteraMinhaVar', valorRetornadoPelaAPI)
  }
}
```

Comment: Problema ainda permanece porque, eu recebo no meu State.user um usuer: {} porque ele está vazio, recebo ele depois de algum tempo e quando faço a chamada do ...mapState(["betaChange"]), no componente ele sobre escreve e logo mantem ele vazio.

Eu teria que isolar ou capturar somente esses dois campos Beta e betaCharts para modificar somente eles, e não consigo fazer essa intervenção somente nesses dois campos sem remontar o objeto inteiro